# I need to cite a classical author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texshop

I have a problem with my [TeXshop] and my bibliography. I need to cite a classical author, concrete `Plinio el viejo`, but when I compile my tex the biblio say `el viejo, Plinio`. Someone know what can I for solve it? I use the biblatex package.

Answer (score 19):

If you have an entry whose author field currently reads

```
author = "Plinio el viejo",
```

BibTeX and biblatex (biber) will interpret "el" as the "von" component of the person's full name, and therefore also "viejo" as the surname component and "Plinio" as the first-name component of the full name. Obviously, that's not what you want for this entry.

To indicate to BibTeX and biblatex that the author has a single composite name, you should write either

```
author = "{Plinio el viejo}",
```

or

```
author = {{Plinio el viejo}},
```

Adding the pair of curly braces tells BibTeX and biber not to parse the author's full name and, in essence, treat it as a multi-component single name. That way, the entry will also be sorted under "P" for "Plinio" rather than under "E" for "el viejo".

---

Here's a full MWE :

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{plinio:77a,
  author = "Plinio el viejo",
  title  = "Naturalis {Historia}",
  year   = {{77}},
}
@misc{plinio:77b,
  author = "{Plinio el viejo}",
  title  = "Naturalis {Historia}",
  year   = {{77}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,useprefix=true,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{plinio:77a}, \citet{plinio:77b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `author={Plinius Secundus, C., senior}`

Answer (score 4):

Especially for classic authors and text you can use the biblatex-style [archaeologie](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/archaeologie).

The special thing is the various versions of an ancient author you can use.
There is the common/known way, like "Pliny the Elder" which is stored in `shortauthor`. Since the way of referencing to classic books is rather specified (e.g. "Plin. nat.") you can use the field `shorthand` for that. And for a complete transcript of the name use the ordinary field `author` for it with the latin/greek way of the name: "Plinius Secundus, Caius".

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{plinius.bib}
@Book{Plin_nat,
  author       = {Plinius Secundus, Caius},
  editor       = {Roderich König and Gerhard Winkler},
  title        = {Naturkunde},
  publisher    = AWi,
  location     = {Düsseldorf},
  origlanguage = {latin},
  origtitle    = {Naturalis historia},
  translator   = {Roderich König and Gerhard Winkler},
  shorthand    = {Plin. nat.},
  shortauthor  = {{Pliny the Elder}},
  keywords     = {ancient},
  options      = {ancient},
  date         = {1997/2007},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=archaeologie,publisher,width=7em]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{plinius.bib}
\begin{document}
This is how \citeauthor{Plin_nat} describes it in \citetitle{Plin_nat}.\footcite[77,12,3]{Plin_nat}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Careful, BibTeX gives errors/nonsense with non-ASCII characters. Need to write "K{\" o}nig".

Comment: i am using lualatex for compiling, no error given then.